# Trouble with setting up vscode Theme color

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've installed iceberg theme extension on vscode, and spend decent amount of time to figure out how to change the color of line number in the way to be the same like code section background color. [What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHInP.png)

I want something like in dark+ (default dark) where both sections have same color

[What I would like to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kKUC.png)

Is it possible to override only line number column color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add these to your settings.json:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
"editorLineNumber.froeground":         ,
"editorGutter.background":             ,
"editorCursor.foreground":             ,
},
```

Choose the color you like and save the changes. Hope hepful.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 workbench colors for line numbers

- `editorLineNumber.foreground`
- `editorLineNumber.activeForeground`

Set both color names to the same color in your `settings.json` file specific for this theme.

Answer (score 0):

After some more searching I found editorGutter.background responsible for setting that thing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).